# PHP uploading multiple images return error on uppercase

Tags: javascript, php, html, input

I have this strange yet annoying error when uploading multiple images.
This does not happen uploading one image!!!

If the files are in lower case it works fine, but if they are in uppercase it just returns Error on the ajaxSubmit success option.

I have code to lower the caracters the thing it straight up skips the php code and returns "Error" on the success option.

This is the html input

```
<input name="gb[]" type="file" class="j_gallery" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
```

Not sure if any more code is necessary since it completly skips the php..

Any hints?

EDIT:

```
$('form[name="editpost"]').submit(function(){   
        var form = $(this);
        var bar = $('.j_editposts .progress');
        var per = $('.j_editposts .progress .bar');
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            url: url,
            data: {acao: 'posts_update'},
            beforeSubmit: function(){
                $('.accept').fadeOut("fast");
                $('.j_editpostimgload').fadeIn("fast");
                $('.j_editposts .title img').fadeIn("fast");
            },
            uploadProgress: function(evento, posicao, total, completo){

            },
            success: function(resposta){
                alert(resposta);
                }   
            },
            complete: function(){
                $('.j_editpostimgload').fadeOut("fast");
                $('.j_editposts .title img').fadeOut("fast");
                bar.fadeOut("fast",function(){
                    $('.accept').fadeIn("fast");
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

php

```
case 'posts_update':
        sleep(1);
        $postid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postid']);

        (...code)

        //Validação da capa
        if($_FILES['cover']['tmp_name']):

        endif;

        //Validação da imagem real
        if($_FILES['realcover']['tmp_name']):

        endif;

        //Validação da galeria

        if($_FILES['gb']['tmp_name']){
            $count = count($_FILES['gb']['tmp_name']);  
            $gb = $_FILES['gb'];
            $pasta = '../../uploads/';

            //gerador de pastas
            $m = date('m');
            $y = date('Y');
            if(!file_exists($pasta.'gallery')): mkdir($pasta.'gallery',0755);   endif;
            if(!file_exists($pasta.'gallery/'.$y)): mkdir($pasta.'gallery/'.$y,0755);   endif;
            if(!file_exists($pasta.'gallery/'.$y.'/'.$m)): mkdir($pasta.'gallery/'.$y.'/'.$m,0755);endif;

            for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++):
                $ext = strrchr($gb['name'][$i],'.');
                $ext = strtolower($ext);

                $baseDir = 'gallery/'.$y.'/'.$m.'/';
                $capaName = $baseDir.$postid.'-'.$i.time().$ext;

                $extePerm = array('image/jpeg','image/pjpeg','image/png','image/gif');

                if(in_array($gb['type'][$i],$extePerm)):
                    $cadastra = array('post_id' => $postid, 'imagem' => $capaName, 'uploaded' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                    create('posts_gallery',$cadastra);
                    uploadImage($gb['tmp_name'][$i],$capaName,800,$pasta);
                    echo ' sendgb';
                endif;
            endfor;
        }
        update('posts',$f,"id = '$postid'");
    break;
```

Comment: You have to post the code as well, the input itself doesn't have issues with case.

Comment: The input is only telling us that you are submitting an array of files. Show the php script that handles the upload.

Comment: What is the error that gets returned? If your php code is not being executed, can you confirm that your client is actually sending the files?

Comment: that's really strange, share your code. need to see more to hint.

Comment: I've updated with the js code.
It uploads one uppercase image, it skips php code if its more than one.
I know this by debugging the php, it ignores and pops the JS alert.

Comment: No answers.. Anyone? Can't find solution to this strange bug(?)